# Hazelcast High Response Times

Tags: hazelcast

We have a Java 1.6 application that uses Hazelcast 3.7.4 version, 
with a topology of two nodes. The application operates mainly with 3 maps.

In normal application working, response times when consulting the maps are
generally in values around some milliseconds tens.

I have observed that in some circumstances such as for example with network
cuts, the response time increases to huge values such as for example, 20 or 30 seconds!!
And this is impacting the application performance.

I would like to know if this kind of situation with network micro-cuts can lead
to increase searches response time in this manner. I do not know if some concrete configuration can be done to minimize this, and also which other elements can provoke so high times.

I provide some examples of some executed consults

Example 1:

```
String sqlPredicate = "acui='"+acui+"'";
Collection<Agent> agents = 
(Collection<Agent>) data.getMapAgents().values(new SqlPredicate(sqlPredicate));
```

Example 2:

```
boolean exist = data.getMapAgents().containsKey(agent);
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Best Regards,
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

The Map operations are all TCP Socket based and thus are subject to your Operating Systems TCP Driver implementation.
See [TCP_NODELAY](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.2/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-Application_Tuning_and_Deployment-TCP_NODELAY_and_Small_Buffer_Writes.html)